# String concatenation when trying to copy arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm confused as to what is causing this behavior in my program.  I'm just trying to copy the contents of one `char*` array to another and instead of copying the element, but it's concatenating the strings in a strange way.  I'm doing something like this:

```
char* a[50]; 
char* b[50];

for(int n=0; n<x; n++){
    a[n] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(b[n])));
    strcpy(a[n], b[n]);
}
```

Has anyone experienced this before?  I can post my output if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the declarations of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @chrisaycock, Sure, I'll add them.

Comment: How do you assign values to b[]? PS: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: are you sure the strings stored under each element of b (b can contain 50 strings) are null terminated?  And what's the value of x?

Comment: Sure, might as well post the output.

Comment: This isn't what's causing your problem, but that sizeof(char) is unnecessary.  It's defined to be one in C99.

Comment: Maybe the bug is in how you print the result? Please also provide that code.

Comment: @fvu, Should I have appended a null character to the end of all of the b[] strings?

Comment: almost anything can happen if your strings aren't null terminated... literally almost anything

Comment: @Sam yes, otherwise strcpy will continue to copy until it finds a 0 somewhere.

Comment: @fvu, Ok but now I'm getting a segfault while trying to strcat() the null character to the elements.

Comment: @Sam: if they are not null terminated to start with strcat() will not be able to find the end of the string to append to.

Comment: @Sam: What I always do with untrusted string input is to place a null terminator myself where the string is supposed to end. If the buffer is 1024 bytes and I just read 1024 bytes of string that is supposed to be null terminated, I do buffer[1023] = '\0' just to be safe.

Comment: @ZanLynx, Ok but must I always explicitly add the null character to the end of a string?  (I'm a little new to C, sorry.)

Comment: @Sam: No you do not always need to do it. Once you *know* the string is terminated then use it normally. If you are reading it from disk or the network then always place your own null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

You loop while `n < x`.  What is `x`?  If `x >= 50`, you'll run off the end of your arrays.  Your loop condition needs to protect against this possibility.

Also, remember that the memory returned by `malloc` is uninitialized.  It is good that you are allocating an extra byte for the NULL terminator.  What you are missing is the code that actually sets the value of the NULL terminator.  The consequence of this is that your `a[]` strings are most likely not NULL-terminated (the last character is whatever random garbage that was previously stored in that byte).  When you try to print them out or use a string function like `strlen` on it, you'll read past the end of the string and into whatever happens to be sitting in the memory range that follows.

Comment: If your sequence of `malloc` calls happen to return consecutive, contiguous chunks memory, then the lack of a NULL terminator could result in something that looks like all of the strings concatenated together by random characters (which seems to match the problem you are describing).

Comment: `strcpy` adds the 0-terminator, so `a[n]` is 0-terminated. If any of the `b[n]`s isn't, that would be a problem, but the only problem with the `a[n]` is that `malloc` might have returned `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using strncpy, note that you have add the null termination character at the end of a[n], This way you are sure to know what you are copying rather relying on the assumption that b[n] has null terminating character.